# Global XAML resource dictionary in C# class library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I have two applications written in C# using WPF for the UI. I moved common UI elements into a separate library to be able to use those elements in both applications. Previously I merged all global resources (like button templates, text styles, ...) into the global resource dictionary in App.xaml, so I didn't have to reference them in each UI element to be able to reference them.

I couldn't find any global dictionary in the Class Library, so currently I do not get any preview in the Designer of UI elements within the Class Libary, because the global resource could not be found. At runtime the resources are still found, because I have merged the global resource dictionaries from the library into the global dictionary in App.xaml in the two Applications.

Is there any way to either use a global resource dictionary in the library? Alternatively is it possible to configure the Visual Studio Designer to always include a specific resource dictionary, in which I merge all global resource dictionaries?